# In React, how can I use one of my props to map my JSON?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, json, react-props

I want to use **props.type** to edit the mapping of the JSON in the **H5**, similar to what I did with the className, but I can't find the correct way to do it.

```
import text from "../../text/global.json";

function Card(props) {
  let col = props.col;
  let type = props.type;

  return (
    <>
      <Col className={`bg-white p-4 card-b col-md-${col}`}>
        <h5>{text.homepage.servicios.cards.${type}.title}</h5>
        <p>Litigio, Microfinanzas, Responsabilidad social y sustentabilidad.</p>
        <Button>Ver más</Button>
      </Col>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried the same way I use for the className, hoping to use the prop as a string but it didn't worked.

Comment: you can access an object key using [key] when it's key is a variable.

Example: 

`<h5>{text.homepage.servicios.cards[type].title}</h5>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For **dynamic property(type)** you have to use square brackets `[]`. I mean to say like this `text.homepage.servicios.cards[type].title`

```
import text from "../../text/global.json";

function Card(props) {
  let col = props.col;
  let type = props.type;

  return (
    <>
      <Col className={`bg-white p-4 card-b col-md-${col}`}>
        <h5>{text.homepage.servicios.cards[type].title}</h5>
        <p>Litigio, Microfinanzas, Responsabilidad social y sustentabilidad.</p>
        <Button>Ver más</Button>
      </Col>
    </>
  );
}
```